# How can I tell gdb to show assembly lines instead of source code lines?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, linux-kernel, gdb

I'm debugging Linux kernel code and instead of showing source code lines like

```
(gdb) 
5588    init_cgroup_root(&cgrp_dfl_root, &opts);
```

I want to see the instructions like

```
(gdb)  
        call 0x23498722 <start_kernel>
```

How can I tell gdb to do this?

Answer (score 3):

use `disassemble` followed by the line of the code. if you don't know the line, you can set a breakpoint at the function and when the execution reaches that function it will give you the adress.

EDIT:
probably a better solution for what you're asking could be `set disassemble-next-line on`

then you set the breakpoint wherever you need it and proceed regularly. gdb will output assembly instructions instead of source code

Comment: That's a good hint but actually not what I want. I only want to see `call 0x23498722 <start_kernel>`. So actually I don't want to see any kind of source code at all. I already managed to do this some time ago but don't remember how I did it. I'm pretty sure I have to tell the Linux Kernel config not to put the source code lines into `vmlinux`, but how?

Answer (score 0):

in gdb cmdline:

gdb>si    or  gdb>x/Ni  address(the code address)

[image]

Comment: Nice hint but not what I want, see my comment above.